# How to deploy more than one contract with Remix

Tags: remix, erc-20, contract-deployment, ropsten, crowdsale

I'm trying to deploy my contracts with Remix to Ropsten, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me? 
(I have a ERC20 token contract, and a CrowdSale contract)

Comment: The title of the question and the body of the question imply two different things. If you know how to deploy one contract, then what exactly is stopping you from doing the same thing for several contracts? Also, " i don't know how to do it. Can you help me?" is not quite sufficient here. Please explain what exactly it is that you don't know, what you've tried, and what problem you've encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply deploy them as separate contracts.

On the "DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTIONS" section of Remix, you can choose which  contract you want to deploy, even if they are in the same file.

[image: contracts]

When you have chosen your contract, simply hit "Deploy" on that same page.

[image: deploy]

You can choose your network by specifying the "Environment" (on that same page) and choosing "Injected Web3".